# Optimize container and typography when converting layouts with 1920px width

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

hello everyone i would like to ask I have trouble converting the layout to html with the design file 1920px wide. How to optimize containers and typography when responsive. I want the font-size and line-height to shrink when resizing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.example {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .example {font-size:0.8rem;line-height:28px}
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .example {font-size:0.9rem;line-height:28px}
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .example {font-size:0.95rem;line-height:28px}
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .example {font-size:1rem;line-height:28px}
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1920px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  .example {font-size:1rem;line-height:28px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Typical Media Query Breakpoints</h2>
<p class="example">Resize the browser window to see how the background color of this paragraph changes on different screen sizes.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your welcome ... if my answer helps you ... you makes me happy by vote this answer is useful for you